# VBA code to get Near By location from url to excel

Tags: vba, web-scraping, msxml

I am trying to get Connectivity,Infrastructure and Neighborhood information from url to excel below is the vba code which i have tried but i am getting error-Run Time Error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set.

```html
Sub test()
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
.Open "GET", "https://www.99acres.com/dasnac-the-jewel-of-noida-sector-75-noida-npxid-r14046?src=NPSRP&sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzEjICB8IG5vaWRhIzUjIHwgQ1AyNSB8IFkgIzE4I3wgIHwgMjUgfCMzIyAgfCA3ICM1I3wgIHwgMjMgfCM0MyMgIHw="
.Send
oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
ele3 = oHtml.getElementById("locHighlightsSlide")
Range("A1") = ele3.innerText
End Sub
```

Below is my html code

```html
<div class="vsp-SliderBar" id="locHighlightsSlide">
                    <div class="amnLeftScroll noVis amenitiesScrollArrow dev_leftlocHightlights">        
                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_leftarrow1x"></i>            
                    </div>
                    <div class="vsp-container">
                        <div class="vsp-itemsFilm clearAfter animTransMrg350">
                                                <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard">
                            <div class="highlightsCardHeading">Connectivity</div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_metro"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Wave City Centr...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Wave City Centre</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">4 km | 20 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_metro"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Golf Course Sta...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Golf Course Station</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">5 km | 25 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard" id="viewMore_Connectivity" style="display: none;">
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_metro"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Wave City Centr...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Wave City Centre</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">4 km | 20 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_metro"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Golf Course Sta...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Golf Course Station</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">5 km | 25 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard">
                            <div class="highlightsCardHeading">Infrastructure</div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_education"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Manav Rachna In...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Manav Rachna International School</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">2 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_education"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Global Indian I...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Global Indian International School</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">2 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_health"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Neo Hospital</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard" id="viewMore_Infrastructure" style="display: none;">
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_education"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Manav Rachna In...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Manav Rachna International School</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">2 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_education"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Global Indian I...</span>
                                        <span class="overflowItem" style="top:auto;z-index: 1">Global Indian International School</span>                                                                            </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">2 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_health"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Neo Hospital</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard">
                            <div class="highlightsCardHeading">Neighborhood</div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-72</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-76</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-51</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="vsp-item highlightsCard" id="viewMore_Neighborhood" style="display: none;">
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-72</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-76</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                            <div class="highlightsCardRow jsinteraction rel" style="overflow: visible;">
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">
                                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_loc_village"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol jsinteraction" style="overflow: visible;">
                                        <span class="highlightPoint">Sector-51</span>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                    <div class="highlightsCardCol">3 km | 15 min</div>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amnRightScroll amenitiesScrollArrow dev_rightLocHighlights">                  
                        <i class="xid_icons xid_icons_1x xid_rightarrow1x dev_vsp-Next"></i>            
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please find the below pic which shows the data which i require.

[image]

Comment: Which information you need from those fields: the logos? You dont even find it necessary to clarify your question as to how your output might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors which are patterns used to select element(s). For your HTML example patterns that work are:

1. First column with: `.vsp-item.highlightsCard:first-child`
2. Second column with: `.vsp-item.highlightsCard:nth-child(2)`
3. Third column with: `.vsp-item.highlightsCard:last-child`
4. Headers with: `.highlightsCardHeading`

The `.` , in the above selectors, is the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) i.e. selecting elements by `className`.

---

**CSS query results**:

*Column 1 Connectivity:*

[image: Column 1]

*Column 2 Infrastructure:*

[image: Column 2]

*Column 3 Neighbourhood:*

[image: Column 3]

*Headers:*

[image: Headers]

Observations: The query results above indicate that a single node i.e. `.querySelector` is required for `Columns 1-3`; note that `0` is the only match returned. Whereas, `.querySelectorAll` will be required for `Headers`, returning a nodeList, as  we can see `0-2` returned.

---

**VBA:**

I cannot access the website to query but the `.querySelector` method belongs to the HTMLDocument and is generally (using your HTMLDocument variable `oHTML`):

For a single node:

```
oHtml.querySelector(".vsp-item.highlightsCard:first-child")
```

For a nodeList:

```
oHtml.querySelectorAll(".highlightsCardHeading")
```

If a nodeList, you iterate over its items with:

```
Dim headerNodeList As Object, i As Long
Set headerNodeList = oHtml.querySelectorAll(".highlightsCardHeading")

For i = 0 To headerNodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print headerNodeList.item(i).innerText '<==this way          '
   'Debug.Print headerNodeList(i).innerText    '<==Or this method
Next i
```

For a single element use `.querySelector` and `.innerText`:

```
Dim col1Node As Object: Set col1Node = oHtml.querySelector(".vsp-item.highlightsCard:first-child"): Debug.Print col1Node.innerText
Dim col2Node As Object: Set col2Node = oHtml.querySelector(".vsp-item.highlightsCard:nth-child(2)"): Debug.Print col2Node.innerText
Dim col3Node As Object: Set col3Node = oHtml.querySelector(".vsp-item.highlightsCard:last-child") : Debug.Print col3Node.innerText
```

---

**Notes:**

I cannot inspect the `.responseText` from your request (Or rather, it is not meaningful due to connection to site failing). It may be that this method will not return the required information, particularly with dynamically loaded pages. Though, I believe `WinHTTPRequest.5.1` has a response status you could use.

In that case you may need to use another method such as IE browser based and wait for page to load. You would still use `.querySelector` or `.querySelectorAll` method of `HTMLDocument`.

---

**Example scripts:**

1. Method for `IE` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613063/6241235
2. Method for `WinHTTP`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759945/6241235 OR https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757822/6241235

---

**Info:**

1. [HTMLDOM querySelector() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)
2. [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Hi QHarr, Thanks for your great help!!! you provided complete information that's really help me!!!!

Comment: Pleasure @saransh